# QNX shell loop sequence

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, qnx

Both following examples work in modern Bash but don't work in different sh shells (like QNX shell).

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3

$ for i in $(seq 1 3); do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

Is there any alternative method to produce same sequence in QNX shell?

Comment: Which QNX shell? Which version of QNX? The docs say ksh is the current shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a method which works in QNX shell:

```
integer i=0
while ((i<4)); do i=i+1; echo $i; done
```

Comment: This works, but `for ((i = 1; i <=3; i++ ))` doesn't? Is this QNX 4? What is it running on?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple workaround to simulate the `expr` hack.

```
yes |
head -n 3 |
nl |
while read i yes; do
  ....
done
```

If you don't care about the value of `i` you can take out the `nl` line numbering.

Comment: +1 Nice technique.  I imagine if `expr` is missing, `nl` and/or `yes` is probably missing as well, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `seq` or `jot`. You may need to use backticks instead of `$()`.

```
for i in `seq 1 3`
```

If the shell in the version of QNX you're using is ksh, then you should be able to use C-style `for` loops:

```
for ((i = 1; i <=3; i++ ))
```

**Edit:**

I'm now guessing that you have QNX 4 which has a ksh86 clone as its shell. In my opinion, under these circumstances, it is brain dead to not include `seq` or `jot`. However, all that aside, here is a hack that *should* be able to do sequences:

```
end=3
for n in $(echo "for (i = 1; i <= $end; i++) i" | bc)
do
    echo "$n"
done
```

Comment: @psihodelia: `seq` is not in any shell that I'm aware of. It's an external utility.

Comment: Yes, sure, but my question is "Is there any alternative method to produce same sequence in QNX shell?"

Comment: # for ((i = 1; i <=3; i++ ))
sh: syntax error: `((' unexpected

Comment: @psihodelia: What does `echo "$((3 + 4))` output?

Comment: It doesn't work cause my QNX has no bc tool. But echo "$((3 + 4))" prints 7

Answer (score 0):

Any posix compliant shell will allow you to iterate:

```
i=1
while expr $i \< 4 > /dev/null; do
  echo $i
  : $(( i + 1 ))
done
```

If you have an older shell, you may need to replace the last line inside the loop with
`i=$( expr $i + 1 )`, and in some rare instances you may need to use back ticks.

Comment: Thank you, looks like the right direction. But my shell doesn't have 'expr' tool. Is there any other method to substitute expr'?

Answer (score 0):

You can get bash for QNX from the NetBSD pkgsrc repository:
ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/QNX/i386/6.5.0_head_20110826/shells/